# Extract specific records/fields with PyFileMaker

Tags: python, regex, windows, filemaker

Python 2.7.
With PyFileMaker, I can acess a FileMaker (FM) Server, open a DB, open a Table (Layout), but I can't (easily) access to specific records and fields. I would like to know how extract specific values from Tables

- **What I can do**

Here it's my manner to loop into the DB to extract records.

```
for i in range (25):
    try:
         a= fm.doFind(id_monument = i)
         L.append(a)
    except:
         pass
```

Considering that `(25)` is the number of records (but it should have a better way to loop through the DB). `L` is a list to stock results. Results are, for the first cell of the list:

```
>>> L[0]
<PyFileMaker.FMResultset.FMResultset instance WITH LIST OF 1 RECORDS (total-count     is     327)>
[MODID = '0'
RECORDID = '236'
fk_Lieudec = '00002'
fk_auteur_fiche = '00001'
(...)
```

Each cell of `L` is a record of the FM DB. `F[0]` type is `<type 'instance'>` (Wasa ?)

- **What I want to do**

1) Extract all records ID and then loop on these ID

2) Extract only specific records. For example where `'fk_Lieudec' LIKE '*2*'`

3) Extract only specific fields. For example, for each records, extract ID and X, Y coordinates.

I'm actually looking at the `regex` to do this... Is it the good way ? Generally, where is the information on PyFileMaker on Internet ?

Comment: By chance, do you know which versions of FileMaker are supported?

Answer (score 0):

the way you're doing will hit FMServer as many times as loop counter. If you install the new version of [PyFileMaker](https://github.com/aeguana/PyFileMaker) from the new GitHub repo, you'll be able to execute `findQuery` and pass list of IDs into the function like that:

```
fm = FMServer('login:password@filemaker.server.com','dbname','layoutname')

results = fm.doFindQuery({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],})
for entry in results: print entry
```

It is even possible to combine queries like that:

```
fm.doFindQuery({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'color': ['red', 'blue'], '!gender': 'm'})
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/aeguana/PyFileMaker/tree/master/Examples) for more examples.

Cheers